# Как применить стили к коментариям?

Tags: php, html, css

В текстовом файле как мне применить стили к комментариям? то есть например автоматические рамки и т.д

```
<?php
$filename = 'templates/comments.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");

$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo $contents;
?>
```

Как применить css в этот код? он выводит комментарии на сайт из текстового файла. Мне нужно что бы они автоматически появлялись со стилями

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<p class="myStyle">'.$contents.'</p>';
```